# WorkFlow Field Update using MetaData Tooling Api Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How to Create WorkFlow Field Update using MetaData Tooling Api

I am creating a metadataservice class and that object . thorw a object i am creating workflow field update but it is not working

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId().substring(0, 15) + ' ' + UserInfo.getSessionId().substring(15);
MetadataService.WorkflowFieldUpdate workflowFieldUpdate = new MetadataService.WorkflowFieldUpdate();

```
// Workflow Field Update
workflowFieldUpdate.fullName           = 'TEST_Active_Permission';
workflowFieldUpdate.description        = 'Activates a permission.';
workflowFieldUpdate.field              = 'Expense__c.Status__c';
workflowFieldUpdate.literalValue       = '1';
workflowFieldUpdate.name               = 'TEST Active Permission';
workflowFieldUpdate.notifyAssignee     = false;
workflowFieldUpdate.operation          = 'Literal';
workflowFieldUpdate.protected_x        = false;
workflowFieldUpdate.reevaluateOnChange = true;
workflowFieldUpdate.targetObject       = 'Expense__c';


MetadataService.WorkflowAction wfp = workflowFieldUpdate;
MetadataService.Metadata[] theMetadata = new MetadataService.Metadata[]{};
theMetadata.add(wfp);


MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = service.createMetadata(theMetadata);
system.debug('results'+results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not Tooling API, that's old school Metadata API. Somebody took the metadata API WSDL file and imported it back to SF. What error are you getting?

Keep in mind that since Winter'23 release (~September 2022) you can't create new workflow rules. Button is disabled in UI too. Field updates... you probably still can but why do you cling to retired automation?

https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/go-with-the-flow-whats-happening-with-workflow-rules-and-process-builder

Note that in Metadata API documentation there's no top-level entry for WorkflowFieldUpdate. It's possible you have to create Workflow, wrap your thing in it. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm Tooling API has separate entry (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowfieldupdate.htm) but you'd need to ditch this hack and use JSON.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your knowledge And Answer.

This document is very useful for me. yes I know  Winter'23 release  not  use any kind of work flow but currently . I am creating a one package and directly we can't assign Approval process and work flow so that is the reason to I am creating a work flow using metadata.

Comment: Flows have submit for approval action too.